# Weekly report on how many contacts entered all active journies?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, reporting

looking for a way to automate a weekly report on all running journies to see how many contacts entered each one. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Look into the journey history api endpoint: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to track the number of contacts that have been sent to per journey, there are a few solutions available:

1. Utilizing the reports and pivot tables in the Intelligence reporting
   feature. This will enable you to schedule regular reports to be
   delivered to your email.
2. Creating a more tailored solution by using SQL queries with the
   Journey Data Views. This allows for a more granular view of your
   journey data and contacts.

Additionally, to access detailed journey entries, as previously mentioned by zuzannamj, you'll need to utilize the Journey History API.